# How do I get Selenium webdriver to use the cookies that are stored in my browser for automatically writing a script to test Tinder?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, cookies, junit, tinder

I am writing a Selenium script which is supposed to automatically log into the tinder website and perform some actions. The problem is that I would like the webdriver script to make use of the cookies used in my browser, which is not currently happening. For example, I would like the Selenium script to log into tinder using facebook and using the facebook credentials that are automatically stored in my browser but this is not working. My current script clicks on Log in with Facebook and prompts me to enter my email and password and then leads to a new page in which I am supposed to input an authentication code which was sent to my phone. I would like to avoid all this trouble and make use of the cookies stored in my browser. How can I do so?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
package Test;

// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MounaTest {
  private static WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @AfterAll
  public static void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA");

    driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.get("https://tinder.com/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Miw\\(120px\\) .l17p5q9z")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Miw\\(120px\\) .l17p5q9z"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    vars.put("window_handles", driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".My\\(12px\\):nth-child(2) .Mend\\(a\\):nth-child(2)")).click();
    vars.put("root", driver.getWindowHandle());
    driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("win1725").toString());
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("root").toString());
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies can be used by encrypting them just like what is shown below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class addCookie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            driver.get("http://www.example.com");

            // Adds the cookie into current browser context
            driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```